# order/sort data frame with respect to a character reference list

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider these two df examples

```
df1=data.frame(names=c('a','b','c'),value=1:3)
df2=data.frame(names=c('c','a','b'),value=1:3)
```

so that

```
> df1
  names value
1     a     1
2     b     2
3     c     3
> df2
  names value
1     c     1
2     a     2
3     b     3
```

Now, I would like to sort the `df1` to the same order as the `names` column in `df2`, to obtain

```
names value
c     3
a     1
b     2
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
df1[match(df2$names,df1$names),]

> df1[match(df2$names,df1$names),]
  names value
3     c     3
1     a     1
2     b     2
```

Comment: Thanks, so match is my function :)